# Integral sign cut off in Safari

Tags: bug, mathjax

I am using Safari version 16.1 with the HTML-CSS renderer.  A displayed formula in the post [Convergence by parameter involving inf](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435270/convergence-by-parameter-involving-inf) renders as follows:

[image: Integral sign is cut off]

This happens even with extensions disabled, but only when I am logged in; if I log out and view the same page, it does not render cut off like this.  It also does not happen with other renderers, or in Firefox, even if I am logged in.

@GeraldEdgar [points out](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5513/integral-sign-cut-off-in-safari/5514#comment28018_5514) an MMSE post [Integral signs not being rendered correctly](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12179) describing the same problem, 8 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment**  I have seen this in the past.  Currently, I do not see it.
Questions for diagnosis:

What math renderer are you using?

> [image: menu]

Does your error persist with others?

What System version?  What version of Safari?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I am using the HTML-CSS renderer with Safari 16.1.  The error does not persist with other renderers.  I am running macOS 12.6.1.

Comment: For a previous instance of the problem, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12179/442

Comment: [Thanks](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5513/integral-sign-cut-off-in-safari/5514#comment28018_5514)!  I have edited your link into the question.